# how to remove deepin desktop environment from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, deepin-desktop-environment

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 with default ubuntu-desktop. Recently I have installed the Deepin Desktop Environment. I think it is affecting the performance of my system so I want to remove one of them. Can I remove the ubuntu-desktop environment? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Start in text-only mode

Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.

```
    Select the line which starts with Advanced options.
    Select the line ending with (recovery mode)
    Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
```

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt.

```
Press Return with this option highlighted.
```

The PC will start in a terminal.

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of deepin that are not necessary in Ubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(deepin),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall ubuntu-desktop

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```